# Confusion surrounding Blackbody formula and Planck's Law

Tags: thermal-radiation

I'm currently in a class addressing blackbody radiation and Planck's Law. I was looking for a derivation of it - I'm fairly mathematically minded, so I would like to see as mathematical a derivation as possible. However, everything I found has said that the Blackbody formula gives the spectral radiance, and the derivation involves spectral energy density. These two quantities are in some strange units (with spectral radiance being given by something like flux per solid angle per area per frequency), and I cannot find a very good definition of either of these quantities. Further, my class gives the Blackbody formula as a formula for intensity, which seemingly is not in agreement with any resources I find online.

What are some good definitions and intuition of terms like spectral radiance and spectral energy density? Further, what would be a good place to find a derivation of the Planck's Law?

Also, I wasn't sure what to tag this - if there are more appropriate tags, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Planck's law comes from the [statistical mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_mechanics) of a [photon gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_gas). There are two main ingredients in the derivation.

First, you have to find the possible states, or modes, a photon can be in. You limit your attention to a [box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_in_a_box) with side length $L$ (volume $V = L^3$) and search for standing waves. You find that the modes are of the form $\sin\left(\frac{\pi m_x x}{L}\right) \sin\left(\frac{\pi m_y y}{L}\right) \sin\left(\frac{\pi m_z z}{L}\right)$ with $m_x$, $m_y$ and $m_z$ positive integers, which corresponds to the wavevector $\vec{k} = \frac{\pi}{L}(m_x, m_y, m_z)$. Thus each state takes up a volume $(\pi/L)^3 = \pi^3 / V$. Looking at the area of the sphere in $\vec{k}$-space with radius $k = \omega / c$, and including a factor $2$ for the two polarisation states of the photon, you eventually find that there are approximately
$$ V \frac{\omega^2}{\pi^2 c^3} d\omega $$
photon states with angular frequency between $\omega$ and $\omega + d\omega$.

Second, you need to remember that a photon has energy $\hbar \omega$ (formally, you treat each photon mode as a [quantum harmonic oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator) where the excitations are photons). Each mode is thus an independent thermodynamical system with energy levels $E_n = n\hbar\omega$ (I've left out the zero-point energy $\frac{1}{2} \hbar\omega$). The average number of photons in each mode then follows the [Bose–Einstein distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bose%E2%80%93Einstein_statistics), and is
$$ \frac{\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} n e^{-n\hbar\omega/k_B T}}{\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} e^{-n\hbar\omega/k_B T}} = \frac{1}{e^{\hbar\omega/k_B T} - 1}. $$

Now you can get the *energy per volume of photons with angular frequency between $\omega$ and $\omega + d\omega$*, which is called the spectral energy density, by multiplying together the number of states, the number of photons in each state and the energy of each photon:
$$ \frac{\omega^2}{\pi^2 c^3} d\omega
\cdot \frac{1}{e^{\hbar\omega/k_B T} - 1} \cdot \hbar \omega
= \frac{\hbar}{\pi^2 c^3} \frac{\omega^3}{e^{\hbar\omega/k_B T} - 1} d\omega
= \frac{8\pi h}{c^3} \frac{\nu^3}{e^{h\nu/k_B T} - 1} d\nu. $$
In the last step, I have converted angular frequency to frequency ($\omega = 2\pi \nu$).

The spectral radiance is the *energy per time and area of photons with angular frequency between $\omega$ and $\omega + d\omega$ passing through an imaginary surface*. In my opinion, it is less interesting than the energy density, but you can get it by averaging over the photons' velocity vectors somehow. The difference ends up being a factor $\frac{c}{4\pi}$.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer. I have a few questions if you don't mind. 1) when you talk about a state taking up volume, what does that mean? I assume you mean in the phase space with basis $m_x, m_y, m_z$, but wouldn't states just be lattice points, as any other point is just a photon state which is not a long term solution? 2) Where did the V go from finding the area in k-space to plugging it in to the expression for spectral energy density?

Comment: 1) By volume I mean volume in $\vec{k}$-space. $\frac{\omega^2}{\pi^2 c^3}$ is called the [density of states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_of_states). The lattice points are indeed long-term solutions (standing waves), and they are the only ones you should include: in thermodynamics, you only consider energy eigenstates. For a full justification, you would need to look up quantum statistical mechanics. As for why the standing waves are energy eigenstates, it's actually quantum optics, but you can sort of pretend it's regular quantum mechanics with a photon wavefunction.

Comment: 2) I just divided by $V$ to get the energy _density_, i.e. the amount of energy per volume.